# Regular expression - look-behind

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I have such input string:

```
left/1234567890
```

regular expression:

```
(left(?<=/)[0-9]{10}?)
```

I want to get such result: 1234567890.
But it doesn't work.

Although, the next input string:

```
/1234567890
```

with the next regular expression:

```
((?<=/)[0-9]{10}?)
```

get result as expected: 1234567890.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you did not include `left` into your lookbehind:

```
((?<=left/)[0-9]{10}?)
```

In your first example, you match `left` then the regex engine's 'pointer' is between `t` and `/`, so your lookbehind cannot match, because the regex engine has not passed the slash yet.